# Exit application not working in some devices

Tags: android, eclipse, webview, exit

Hope I can explain my problem well
I coded an android app in eclipse but all codes run through WebView and JavaInterface
I mean I have a webview in my application and connect to android function via JavaInterface
This app has been coded for Android 5.0 and my problem is just for Exit from app .

```
public void exitFromApp(){

        finish();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(1);



    }
```

This is my exit function and **it works fine on my phone and on eclipse emulator**
but when I want test it on some devices for example my friend'a device ( HUAWEI mobile ) and this website https://www.manymo.com , when I click exit , the app returns to main page of webview and never exit .

Comment: Never used the `killProcess` call myself but IIRC `WebView` has its own thread, perhaps on your phone you are able to use the back button to bring it down?

Comment: Yes on my phone it is . also I forgot to say I coded a function that If user click on BACK button the app will exit very well on all devices but the stand-alone exit link on webview does not work on some devices

Comment: What standalone exit link? My `WebView` is a full screen HTML rendering. Only when I use devices without a back button do I come unstuck, without having implemented my own `ActionBar`-esque control.

Comment: I have a link on my webview <A href="" onclick="Android.exitFromApp()">EXIT</a> this link works fine on some devices and doest work on some others

Answer (score 0):

Try this when you want to exit your app

```
finishAffinity();
```

Comment: Should I add @SuppressLint("NewApi")  at first line ?

Answer (score 0):

I just add these line before my function start and my problem has been solved
now the application will exit by clicking on Exit link on webView

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@JavascriptInterface
```